# DataFilter in alloy.collection titanium

Tags: collections, filtering, models, titanium-alloy

I'm using "dataFilter" with alloy.collection

```
function filterFunction(collection) {
var lang = parseInt(Alloy.Globals.Language);
    return collection.where({
        LangID : lang,
        CategoryID : categoryId
    });
}
```

and it works fine, my question is how can I use this approach with 'or' or 'and', I need to do something like ' where categoryId="1" or categoryId="2" or categoryId="3"'

I used query in fetching and it works fine too, but I want to know if it's possible to do it with dataFilter function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

underscore is installed by default with Alloy I believe so this should work

```
 _.filter(Alloy.Globals.Language, function(i) {
   return i.categoryId==="1" || i.categoryId==="2" || i.categoryId==="3"
});
```